# How to find the maximum length of column value in Long Datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How to find the maximum length of column value in Long Datatype in Oracle, what is the query for finding the maximum length of the column value in Oracle

Comment: Hi, Maybe this is what you're looking for

LONG # Maximum Internal Length 2^31-1 bytes (2 gigabytes)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#LNOCI16265

Comment: Not sure there is an easy way; the `long` data type has been deprecated for quite a while; the current LOB types like `CLOB` and `BLOB` allow you to figure this out.  Of course, Alex probably knows the answer off the top of his head.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the length directly in SQL. You can use a PL/SQL block to examine each long value track the longest, e.g.:

```
declare
  s pls_integer := 0;
begin
  for r in (select long_column from your_table where long_column is not null)
  loop
    s := greatest(s, length(r.long_column));
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('max: ' || s);
end;
/
```

but that's a bit painful.

There is an XML trick you can use though. If your table is called `YOUR_TABLE` and the long column is called `LONG_COLUMN` then you can do:

```
select max(length(clob_value))
from xmltable (
  '/ROWSET/ROW/LONG_COLUMN'
  passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select long_column from your_table'))
  columns clob_value clob path '.'
);
```

Substitute your own table and column name, of course.

You can do something similar to get all the table rows back with each long converted to a CLOB, should you ever need to do that.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ddd6a74ad21da737807f82c7001a94e6)

It may trip over XML entities within the long values though...